# Properly handle Select with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-select

I am new to angular. I have the select declared as such (jade syntax)

```
select(ng-model="projectData.ProjectStatus" ng-options="c.name for c in statuses")
```

and statuses are initialised as

```
$scope.statuses = [
  {name:'Active', value:1},
  {name:'Not active', value: 0}
];
```

In resulting select, nothing is selected and it is rendered as

```
<select
  ng-model="projectData.ProjectStatus"
  ng-options="c.name for c in statuses"
  class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="0">Active</option>
    <option value="1">Not active</option>
</select>
```

How I can specify which option I need to have selected, and how to avoid rendering of first option with "?" so I simply have a select where "Not active" or "active" is already chosen?

Note that $scope.projectData.ProjectStatus IS sent to 1 but it does not seem to be in effect here...

Comment: Maybe I think create currentSelection variable on $scope and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not manually use options tag instead try the below code to make it working

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" >
 <div>
   <select ng-model="projectData.ProjectStatus" ng-options="c.value as c.name for c in data"></select>
</div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('demo', []);
        alert(app);

        app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.data = [{ name: 'Active', value: 1 }, { name: 'Not active', value: 0 }];
            $scope.projectData = { ProjectStatus: 0 }
        });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set default value for select by setting model value in your controller:

`$scope.projectData.ProjectStatus = $scope.statuses[0];`

Also, note that option values rendered in html are actually indexes of array you pass in `ng-options`.
More info in [API Doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select).